# How would I create my own amm or exchange?

Tags: amm

Good afternoon, I have a goal of making my own amm website similar to pancake swap or uniswap and I don't have great first place to start to break ground on actually developing, I have a some what of a grip on programming and know interacting with the chains and making contracts requires solidity, web dev is going to use css and html [airing the two but for a project of this size I am not sure where to start.

Comment: Learn about solidity, existing AMM, web3.js / ethers.js, frontend framework like React, node.js

Answer (score 0):

Take things one step at a time.  I would recommend doing a full tutorial on coding in Solidity to get a strong understanding of this before you start with a bigger project like an AMM.

Take a look at [Cryptozombies](https://cryptozombies.io/en/course).  Once you finish that course, try to get a better understanding of what the full stack of tech that is needed for developing full projects.  I personally like [Nader Dabit](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a0osIaAOFSE) videos for a full explanation on the stack needed for development. Other good resources are [Buildspace](https://buildspace.so/) and [DappUniversity](https://www.youtube.com/c/DappUniversity).

Once you think you have a good understanding, take a look at the source code of popular AMM's, here is a link to [Uniswap's Github](https://github.com/Uniswap).

Also, try to join communities/DAOs of developers. It's much easier to learn with being able to ask questions, but some prefer the solo route. Best of luck on your journey!

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's not really HTML/CSS on the frontend, it's more like Javascript, but that's not really **where the magic happens**.  The magic is in the backend contracts that you deploy yourself on the blockchain.

If you're *really* diligent, you could actually download/compile/deploy the latest uniswap code itself and see how it works.

There is also a whitepaper that explains some of the math behind it.

[Uniswap V3 Core contracts (the bare minimum)](https://github.com/Uniswap/v3-core.git)

[Uniswap V3 peripheral contract (commonly used utilities/helpers)](https://github.com/Uniswap/v3-periphery.git)

[Uniswap V3 White Paper](https://uniswap.org/whitepaper-v3.pdf)